# Mongodb query to Display the number of movies based on the number of directors a movie has using split

Tags: mongodb, split, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a movieDetails.json database and the collection name is a movie then our teacher wants us to Display the number of movies based on the number of directors a movie has
a.  Hint you might have to use the javascript function split
Since the director is not an array, it is only a string so I can't count how many directors are there because it will always come out as 1 since its a string so I want to split that string so that I can get an array so that I can count it. But unfortunately, I don't know the query that will solve this problem.
ex. of expected output:

```
    {_id:1 , value: 100}
    {_id:2 , value: 200}  etc.
```

_id being the number of directors a document has

```
    db.movie.find().pretty()
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b107bec1d2952d0da9046e1"),
            "title" : "A Million Ways to Die in the West",
            "year" : 2014,
            "rated" : "R",
            "runtime" : 116,
            "countries" : [
                    "USA"
            ],
            "genres" : [
                    "Comedy",
                    "Western"
            ],
            "director" : "Seth MacFarlane",
            "writers" : [
                    "Seth MacFarlane",
                    "Alec Sulkin",
                    "Wellesley Wild"
            ],
            "actors" : [
                    "Seth MacFarlane",
                    "Charlize Theron",
                    "Amanda Seyfried",
                    "Liam Neeson"
            ],
            "plot" : "As a cowardly farmer begins to fall for the mysterious new woman in town, he must put his new-found courage to the test when her husband, a notorious gun-slinger, announces his arrival.",
            "poster" : "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ0NDcyNjg0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzk4NTA4MTE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "imdb" : {
                    "id" : "tt2557490",
                    "rating" : 6.1,
                    "votes" : 126592
            },
            "tomato" : {
                    "meter" : 33,
                    "image" : "rotten",
                    "rating" : 4.9,
                    "reviews" : 188,
                    "fresh" : 62,
                    "consensus" : "While it offers a few laughs and boasts a talented cast, Seth MacFarlane's overlong, aimless A Million Ways to Die in the West is a disappointingly scattershot affair.",
                    "userMeter" : 40,
                    "userRating" : 3,
                    "userReviews" : 62945
            },
            "metacritic" : 44,
            "awards" : {
                    "wins" : 0,
                    "nominations" : 6,
                    "text" : "6 nominations."
            },
            "type" : "movie"
    }
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b107bec1d2952d0da9046e3"),
        "title" : "West Side Story",
        "year" : 1961,
        "rated" : "UNRATED",
        "runtime" : 152,
        "countries" : [
                "USA"
        ],
        "genres" : [
                "Crime",
                "Drama",
                "Musical"
        ],
        "director" : "Jerome Robbins, Robert Wise",
        "writers" : [
                "Ernest Lehman",
                "Arthur Laurents",
                "Jerome Robbins"
        ],
        "actors" : [
                "Natalie Wood",
                "Richard Beymer",
                "Russ Tamblyn",
                "Rita Moreno"
        ],
        "plot": "Two youngsters from rival New York City gangs fall in love, but tensions between their respective friends build toward tragedy.",
        "poster" : "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTM0NDAxOTI5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjI4Mjg3NA@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "imdb" : {
                "id" : "tt0055614",
                "rating" : 7.6,
                "votes" : 67824
        },
        "awards" : {
                "wins" : 18,
                "nominations" : 11,
                "text" : "Won 10 Oscars. Another 18 wins & 11 nominations."
        },
        "type" : "movie"
}

            "director" : "Sergio Leone",
            "writers" : [
                    "Sergio Donati",
                    "Sergio Leone",
                    "Dario Argento",
                    "Bernardo Bertolucci",
                    "Sergio Leone"
            ],
            "actors" : [
                    "Claudia Cardinale",
                    "Henry Fonda",
                    "Jason Robards",
                    "Charles Bronson"
            ],
            "plot": "Epic story of a mysterious stranger with a harmonica who joins forces with a notorious desperado to protect a beautiful widow from a ruthless assassin working for the railroad.",
            "poster" : "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTEyODQzNDkzNjVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDgyODk1NDEx._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "imdb" : {
                    "id" : "tt0064116",
                    "rating" : 8.6,
                    "votes" : 201283
            },
            "tomato" : {
                    "meter" : 98,
                    "image" : "certified",
                    "rating" : 9,
                    "reviews" : 54,
                    "fresh" : 53,
                    "consensus" : "A landmark Sergio Leone spaghetti western masterpiece featuring a classic Morricone score.",
                    "userMeter" : 95,
                    "userRating" : 4.3,
                    "userReviews" : 64006
            },
            "metacritic" : 80,
            "awards" : {
                    "wins" : 4,
                    "nominations" : 5,
                    "text" : "4 wins & 5 nominations."
            },
            "type" : "movie"
    }
```

Comment: So here `"director" : "Seth MacFarlane",` means 2 directors ? are they seperated by space ?

Comment: no po, it's the fullname of the director

Comment: Can you add movie record which has multiple directors ?

Comment: The json file is already given by my teacher. That's why I can't add some movie record which has multiple directors since it is already in the database. I just copy and paste only few data on it.

Comment: Yes i get that, from json file can you pick document which has more than 1 director and add that to the question.

Comment: I have already added sir

Comment: Ma'am please check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/y3kvFnocWKn

Use aggregation query

Read the below links for better understanding

[$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/)

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

[$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/)

[$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)

```
db.movie.aggregate([
  {
   $match: { director: { $ne: null } }
  },
  {
    $set: { // set directorsCount
      directorsCount: {
        $size: { // get the size of the array
          $split: ["$director", ","] // split by comma will return array
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$directorsCount", // group by directorsCount
      value: { $sum: 1 } // count
    }
  }
])
```

---

Shorter version

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nt-NDBpN4Ad

```
db.movie.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { director: { $ne: null } }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $size: { $split: [ "$director", "," ] } },
      value: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

---

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/f8fuZVIjc-_

If you want to count records where directors are 0

```
db.movie.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $size: {
          $ifNull: [
            { $split: [ "$director", "," ] },
            []
          ]
        }
      },
      value: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I'll try it, sir.. I'll let you know if this will work po..Thank you so much!

Comment: "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: null",
        "code" : 17124,
        "codeName" : "Location17124"
} : aggregate failed :

Comment: @Lesh Upaded answer check now, added `$match:`

Comment: Thank youuuuu soooo muchhh sirrrrrrrr!! It worked! yeheyyy

Comment: Ok sir noted po! Thank you :)